# Linear algebra solution to tetrahedron geometry problem

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let $PQRS$ be a tetrahedron and let $u=\vec{PQ}$, $v=\vec{PR}$ and $w=\vec{PS}$ form a basis for the 3-dimensional space. Let $H$ be the center of mass of the triangle $PQR$, let $M$ be center of mass of the triangle $QRS$ and let the point $N$ be the center of mass of the tetrahedron. Determine the coordinates of the vectors $\vec{HM}$ , $\vec{HN}$ and $\vec{MN}$ with respect to the basis u, v, w.

This question is very difficult for me. Hopefully someone can give me insight (full solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H = \dfrac{1}{3} (P + Q + R) = \dfrac{1}{3}(3 P + (Q-P) + (R - P) ) = P + \dfrac{1}{3} (u + v) $

Similarly

$ M = \dfrac{1}{3} (Q + R + S) = \dfrac{1}{3}(3 P + (Q - P) + (R - P) + (S - P) ) = P + \dfrac{1}{3} (u + v + w ) $

$N = \dfrac{1}{4} ( P + Q + R + S ) = P + \dfrac{1}{4} (u + v + w)$

$\vec{HM} = M - H = \dfrac{1}{3} w $

$\vec{HN} = N - H = - \dfrac{1}{12} u - \dfrac{1}{12} v + \dfrac{1}{4} w $

$ \vec{MN} = N - M = - \dfrac{1}{12} (u + v + w ) $